# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Go File Permission Problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am currently deploying a Go application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

In the application, I create a file for logging.

When the application deploys, I get an error depending on what I did.

When I
`os.Create("/var/log/golang/golang-server.log")`. I get the following error message back `open /var/log/golang/golang-server.log: no such file or directory`

But when I `os.Create("/var/log/golang-server.log")`. I get the following error message back `open /var/log/golang-server.log: permission denied`

I am currently deploying the example go.zip application they provide on their website to make sure that none of my implementation/code is the problem.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/go-getstarted.html

In there code, they also create a file for logging, but they are ignoring the error from os.Create, and thus the file never gets created.

I have a .ebextension folder that I could use should I need to fix something.

Thank you.

Comment: you need to create the directory, and give it permission (chmod +755: if i remember right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are executing the `os.Create` commands from your application.

Your application executes under `webapp` user, while `/var/log` is owned by `root`. Subsequently you get those errors.

To recitfy the issue, in your `.ebextension` you could have `commands` (or `files`) section which will create a log config file for your application by adding it to `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/logtasks/bundle`.

For example, you can just create:

```
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/logtasks/bundle/my-go-app.conf
```

with the content of

```
/var/app/current/log/*.log
```

where `/var/app/current/log/*.log` would be location of your custom application logs. It can be other location. This is just an example of the config file.

Comment: This worked. In the os.Create I did './golang-server.log' and in the .ebextensions I added a files item where I added that to the bundle/my-go-app.conf. 
Then I just added the /var/app/current/golang-server.log to the cloudwatch export item.

Comment: Glad to hear that :-)